# Sugarsync Cloud - Magic Briefcase folder location

Tags: cloud

I'm using SugarSync on my Windows and Ubuntu. SugarSync doesn't have a native Linux client, so I installed Windows version via Wine. If someone uses it in that way - where a hell is "Magic Briefcase" folder?

I looked in home/.wine/... and found something, but SugarSync don't recognize any changes. Maybe the client don't work via Wine, or I can't find what I looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mochan The answer here is at least somewhat valuable. I recommend we keep this open.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
https://github.com/markwillis82/Sugar-Sync-Linux-Client
and stop searching. I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising